# High Memory Usage with Deeplearning4j during Model Inference

Tags: java, memory-management, neural-network, deeplearning4j, nd4j

I'm experiencing high memory usage issues when performing inference with a neural network model using Deeplearning4j. Despite reducing the number of hidden nodes, the memory consumption remains unexpectedly high.

Here are the details of my setup:

- Deeplearning4j version: deeplearning4j-core:1.0.0-M2
- Backend: ND4J Backend CPU
- Operating System: Mac
- Java version: tried Java 15, Java 21

The model configuration is as follows:

- Number of input nodes: 50
- Number of hidden nodes: 420
- Number of outputs: 7
- Network depth: 10 layers

The issue occurs during the `output` method call, where I observe a memory usage of around 16.33 GB, which seems excessive for the model size. Here is the code snippet where the issue is observed:

```java
Object [] rollout (State stato){
        INDArray p;
        int v;
        if (trained){
            INDArray inputData = stato.toINDArray();
            INDArray[] out;
            out = model.output(inputData);
            p = out[0];
            v = out[1].getInt(0);
        } else {
            //si verifica quando i modelli non sono ancora addestrati, scelgo quindi un valore a caso e assegno una probabilità massima a ogni nodo figlio
            Random r = new Random();
            p = Nd4j.ones(Board.N).mul(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            v = Math.abs(r.nextInt()) % MAXREWWARD;
        }
        Object[] out = {p,v};
        return out;
    }
```

here is my neural network configuration, i am trying to reproduce a version of alphazero

```java
 DeepLearning (int numInputs, int numOutputs, String name, int M, int  N, int X, int nndepth) throws IOException {
        this.numInputs = numInputs;
        this.numHiddenNodes = M*N*10;
        this.numOutputs = numOutputs;
        DeepLearning.M = M;
        DeepLearning.N = N;
        DeepLearning.X = X;
        this.name = name;
        File file = new File("./model" +  name + M + "." + N + "." + X + "." + ".zip");
        if (file.exists()){
            trained = true;
            this.model = ComputationGraph.load(file , true);
        } else {
            ComputationGraphConfiguration.GraphBuilder graphBuilder = new NeuralNetConfiguration.Builder()
                    .seed(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .weightInit(WeightInit.RELU)
                    .l2(1e-4)
                    .updater(new Adam(learningRate))
                    .graphBuilder();
            graphBuilder.addInputs("input")
                    .setInputTypes(InputType.feedForward(numInputs));
            String lastLayer = "input";
            for (int i = 0; i < nndepth; i++) {
                graphBuilder.addLayer("torso_" + i,
                        new DenseLayer.Builder()
                                .nIn(i == 0 ? numInputs : numHiddenNodes)
                                .nOut(numHiddenNodes)
                                .activation(Activation.RELU)
                                .build(),
                        lastLayer);
                lastLayer = "torso_" + i;
            }

            graphBuilder.addLayer("policy_dense",
                    new DenseLayer.Builder()
                            .nIn(numHiddenNodes)
                            .nOut(numHiddenNodes)
                            .activation(Activation.RELU)
                            .build(),
                    lastLayer);
            graphBuilder.addLayer("policy_output",
                    new OutputLayer.Builder(LossFunctions.LossFunction.NEGATIVELOGLIKELIHOOD)
                            .nIn(numHiddenNodes)
                            .nOut(numOutputs)
                            .activation(Activation.SOFTMAX)
                            .build(),
                    "policy_dense");

            graphBuilder.addLayer("value_dense",
                    new DenseLayer.Builder()
                            .nIn(numHiddenNodes)
                            .nOut(numHiddenNodes)
                            .activation(Activation.RELU)
                            .build(),
                    lastLayer);
            graphBuilder.addLayer("value_output",
                    new OutputLayer.Builder(LossFunctions.LossFunction.MSE)
                            .nIn(numHiddenNodes)
                            .nOut(1)
                            .activation(Activation.IDENTITY)
                            .build(),
                    "value_dense");

            graphBuilder.setOutputs("policy_output", "value_output");

            ComputationGraphConfiguration conf = graphBuilder.build();
            model = new ComputationGraph(conf);
        }
        model.init();
        System.out.println("Numero parametri: " + model.numParams());
        this.myReplay = new ReplayBuffer();
    }

    private String addDenseLayer(ComputationGraphConfiguration.GraphBuilder graphBuilder, String inputLayer, String layerName, int nIn, int nOut, Activation activation) {
        graphBuilder.addLayer(layerName, new DenseLayer.Builder()
                .nIn(nIn)
                .nOut(nOut)
                .activation(activation)
                .build(), inputLayer);
        return layerName;
    }
```

I have tried the following troubleshooting steps without success:

Ensuring the use of workspaces to manage memory efficiently.
Using in-place operations to reduce memory allocation.
Reducing batch size during inference.
Checking for memory leaks and ensuring objects are being garbage collected.
The profiler indicates that most of the computation time is spent in the output call of the ComputationGraph.

Here's the memory profile screenshot:
[image: memory usage]

Comment: What's the shape of `inputData`? Are you using batches? If so, what's the batch size? Also, what's the point of convolutional layers with a 1x1 kernel?

Comment: @dan1st i tried kernel of 3x3 because i thought that was a standard plus or minus, but it changed the data shape, inputData shape is 1 channel, 42 batchsize, hight 6 width 7

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea how your code is supposed to run since the number of output nodes of a layer should match the number of input nodes of the next layer. Anyways, you need to expext each dense layer to store around twice the number of input nodes times the number of output nodes variables

Comment: oh and also multiplied with the batch size - for convolution layers, you don't need to store that much information. Oh and forget the 'twice', that's for training and not for inference.

Comment: @dan1st I didn't see where my input didn't match the output, sorry i am obviously new to neural networks, but i've tried to change my code a bit, if u can look at it or  if u can tell me where my input didn't match the output i would be very grateful, thank u in advance

Comment: `policy_output` seems to have `numOutputs` but the next(?) layer (`value_dense`) seems to have `numHiddenNodes` inputs. But I could have made a mistake reading it.

Comment: @dan1st no they are two separate outputs

Comment: I see. How much memory is needed for training?

Comment: @dan1st i don't know really... i'm trying to implement a version of alphazero, and also i have a problem of segmentation falt every 6 hours plus or minus, i am providing also the informations about the segmentation fault now in my question

Comment: Can you please try to reduce it to a [mcve]? Also, your "time problem" seems kind of expected - if you have expensive computations, it will take some time.

Comment: @dan1st i deleted some less important things, is it better?

Comment: I meant that you should try to come up with the most simple possible code/model that others can run to reproduce your issue. Also, please only focus on one thing in your question (e.g. the segmentation fault or the high memory use)

Comment: @dan1st, i deleted the error, but less than the model i am using and the function that cause the problem i think i can't provide if u want to reproduce the error, if u meant that it' not enough then i am sorry, but please clarify what u would like me to provide, like: where i call the function or what

Comment: If it's possible for you, it might be helpful to create a smaller model so you still run into the issue (though probably at a smaller scale) (it's hard to find an issue when you can't reproduce it)